# PHP autocomplete in Eclipse PDT function documentation not formatted

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete

I installed Eclipse with PDT. The autocomplete works, and when the pop-up box comes up it shows a list of functions. The problem is that the descriptions of the functions to the right in another box are not formatted. The description which describe the function and list the parameters is plain text, and has some visible css styling, but it is not parsed as such. This is how the start of the str_getcsv function is described:

```
/* Font definitions */ html { font-family: 'Sans',sans-
serif; font-size: 10pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: 
normal; } body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, table, td, 
caption, th, ul, ol, dl, li, dd, dt { font-size: 1em; } pre 
{ font-family: monospace; } /* Margins */
```

has anybody had this problem. I can't seem to find any reference to this.

Comment: I have tested it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

It's because the library that eclipse uses to render html inside the autocomplete is missing.

In ubuntu or debian you can solve it by installing libwebkitgtk-1.0-0

> sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0

then restart eclipse